# Is adding a Button element inside an Anchor element possible?

Tags: javascript, html, button, anchor

Reading the [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) we can't add into Anchor element a Button element.

So I don't understand I can consider this code valid which seems to work:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.com" id="anchor" target="_blank">
  <span>Click me to go to the website</span> 
  <button id="button">
    Click me to change color!
  </button>
</a>
```

https://codepen.io/ale-grosselle/pen/XWKJmJW

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element  The specs specify that a link cannot contain a button

Comment: "seems to work" isn't the same as "it's guaranteed to work". It just means "the current version of the browser I'm using there are no immediate problems I can see or am aware of".